Queued jobs mail server issue
I have recently updated my mail server in a Laravel application hosted in AWS from Sendgrid to Mailtrap. Everything works fine if I am sending the immediate emails, however when I am trying to send the emails using queued jobs, the jobs are failing every time.
Below is the screenshot of the failed job. Looking into the failed jobs, I can figure out that the jobs are still cached with the old SendGrid settings and not taking up the updated Mailtrap settings.
I have tried rebooting the EC2 instances in AWS so the cache could be cleared. Also, tried running queue:restart from the Application Level. Nothing has helped.

